# How to connect from PgAdmin container to Postgres container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I want to deploy 2 containers one for pgAdmin and one for Postgres with docker-compose. Containers are created correctly and I am able to login to pgAdin on my browser, but when I am trying to create a connection to Postgres, using localhost:15432 it does not work, but if I use 172.19.0.2:15432 it works. Is there a way to use the localhost for the connection or to assign a fixed port to my Postgres?

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: rn_postgres
    image: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: rn2020
      POSTGRES_DB: rnmonitor
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: rn_pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  pgadmin:
  postgres-data:
```

Comment: What about just connecting using hostname rn_postgres?

Comment: @Rolando Azevedo when you connect to PostgreSQL container from your pg_admin using localhost:15432, it will route to the localhost inside the pg_admin network instead of pointing to PostgreSQL Network.

You can connect to your PostgreSQL using the private IP address of the os that you can get using $ ifconfig

Comment: using hostname rn_postgres I have message " is the server running on host "rn_postgres "172.19.0.2" and accepting TCP/IP on port 15432. Using the private IP is a solution if the IP assigned to Postgres anytime a restart is the same. I want to use a Pentaho container, to execute jobs, and inside it uses a connection string, and i am not able to find the IP of the Postgres from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be able to communicate with each other via their `container_name` since `docker-compose` creates a default network for its services

I'm running them separately (not docker-compose way) but still, as long as they're on the same `docker-network` they should be able to talk to each other:

1. Get containers names

```
docker ps

IMAGE                PORTS                         **NAMES**
dpage/pgadmin4      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   pgadmin
postgres            0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp        postgres-demo
```

2. Create a docker network, then attach containers to it

```
docker network create pg-net

docker network connect pg-net pgadmin
docker network connect pg-net postgres-demo
```

3. Then on PGAdmin4's portal:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be connecting 2 postgres containers. Where is the connection to the pgadmin container?

Comment: I edited the answer. It now shows `postgress-demo` & `pgadmin` containers being attached to `pg-net` network